# Skipping "Swipe screen to unlock" screen?

Tags: lock-screens, home-screen, samsung-galaxy-y

I do not have any kind of password/pattern lock enabled in my rooted Samsung Galaxy Y mobile phone.

When I wake my phone up, by pressing either the power button or the middle button, I see this screen:

[image: Swipe screen to unlock in Samsung devices]

What I wish is that I do not get this screen, I directly go to the home screen of my device when I press the power/middle button. How can it be done?

P.S: I have a **rooted** phone.

Comment: This exists so you don't call people by accident in your pocket

Answer (score 2):

Your phone do not need to be rooted. Go to `Settings` > `Security` > `Screen lock`. Then select `None` to disable the lock screen (which should be set to `Swipe` or something like that in your casesince you get the Swipe screen).

Comment: That gives the swipe screen

Comment: The `None` option works on my Android device (and theorically on all ICS devices like mine). It is weird that it does not work in your case.

Comment: I have android 2.3 and not ICS